# ImageView in ListView. Getting AlbumArt

Tags: android, listview, bitmap

I'm trying to put AlbumArt in ImageView placed in ListView.
I don't realize why first example is working and I can put bitmap in ImageView in other Fragment but I cant put bitmap in listview.

```
BookFragment.mAlbumArt.setImageBitmap(bitmap);'
```

is working and 'BookFragment' is other fragment

```
ivListAlbumArt.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

doesn't work

Code

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.library, parent, false);

    ListView lvLibList = (ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.lvLibList);
    ImageButton btAddItem = (ImageButton)view.findViewById(R.id.btAddItem);
    lvLibList.setAdapter(adapter);
    final ImageView ivListAlbumArt = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.ivListAlbumArt);
    mBooks = BookLib.get(getActivity()).getBooks();

    lvLibList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                int position, long id) {

            Book b = (Book)parent.getAdapter().getItem(position);
            String fn = b.getBookFileName();
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, fn);

            musicSrv.releaseMedia();
            musicSrv.initMediaPlayer();
            musicSrv.setMedia(fn);
            musicSrv.createMedia();
            musicSrv.playNewMedia();
            BookFragment.mFileName.setText(musicSrv.getMediaTitle());


            byte[] art = musicSrv.getMediaAlbumArt();
            if(art != null)
            {
                Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(art, 0, art.length);
                BookFragment.mAlbumArt.setImageBitmap(bitmap); 
                BookFragment.mAlbumArt.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
                BookFragment.mAlbumArt.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(800, 800));

                ivListAlbumArt.setImageBitmap(bitmap); 
                ivListAlbumArt.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
                ivListAlbumArt.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(80, 80));
            }
            else
            {
                BookFragment.mAlbumArt.setImageResource(R.drawable.thevoice); 
                BookFragment.mAlbumArt.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
                BookFragment.mAlbumArt.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(800, 800));

                ivListAlbumArt.setImageResource(R.drawable.thevoice); 
                ivListAlbumArt.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
                ivListAlbumArt.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(80, 80));
            }
         }
    });

    BookAdapter bookAdapter = new BookAdapter(mBooks);
    lvLibList.setAdapter(bookAdapter);

    btAddItem.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            OpenFileDialog fileDialog = new OpenFileDialog(getActivity());
            fileDialog.show();
        }
    });

    return view;
}
```

UPD: Adapter code.
Can I add code updating ImageView in Adapter?

```
private class BookAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Book> {
    public BookAdapter(ArrayList<Book> books) {
        super(getActivity(),0,books);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
        }
        Book b = getItem(position);
        TextView tvTitle = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvFileName);
        TextView tvPath = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvFilePath);
        TextView tvListDuration = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvListDuration);
        ImageView ivListAlbumArt = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.ivListAlbumArt);
        tvTitle.setText(b.getTitle());
        tvPath.setText(b.getBookAutor());
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Adapter XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>


<ImageView
    android:layout_width="54dp"
    android:layout_height="54dp"
    android:layout_weight="0"
    android:id="@+id/ivListAlbumArt"
    android:padding="3dp"
    android:src="@drawable/logo" />

 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvFileName"
    android:text="FileName will be here"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/ivListAlbumArt"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvListDuration"
    android:text="0:00"
    android:layout_weight="0"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvFilePath"
    android:text="FilePath will be here"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_below="@id/tvFileName"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/ivListAlbumArt"
    android:padding="5dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

UPD: LogCat output

```
11-14 07:08:31.742    5943-5943/ru.app.a_book W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4159aba8)
11-14 07:08:31.742    5943-5943/ru.app.a_book E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: ru.app.a_book, PID: 5943
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at ru.app.a_book.TabLibrary$2.onItemClick(TabLibrary.java:182) // code: ivListAlbumArt.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:299)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1113)
        at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2911)
        at android.widget.AbsListView$3.run(AbsListView.java:3645)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Why are you trying to set the fragment inside the List View.

Comment: I can't understand about you say. I set image for ListView with ImageView and TextView within the Fragment. At lieast i'm trying to do it

Comment: Why is mAlbumArt static? Is the ListView inside BookFragment? I can't understand your code.

Comment: So. mAlbumArt is working good.
ListView not inside the BookFragment.
I can set image for mAlbumArt but can't for ivListAlbumArt

Comment: @RyndinV Shouldnt you be setting the row of the listview and not the listview itself ?

Comment: where have you initialized `BookFragment.mAlbumArt`???? @RyndinV

Comment: @SweetWisherツ 
    BookFragment: public static ImageView mAlbumArt;

Comment: it is just a declaration.. you need to initialize like : `mAlbumArt= findViewById(R.id.img);`

Comment: @SweetWisherツ BoolFragment.mAlbumArt is working and setting bitmap into ImageView placed other Fragment. But ivListAlbumArt.setImageBitmap doesn't work with same code

Comment: because you have missed initialization.. where is ivListAlbumArt in XML ?? shww the xml

Comment: @Janpan What are you talking about?

Comment: Did you debug whether ivListAlbumArt  is null or bitmap?

Comment: @MysticMagic `byte[] art = musicSrv.getMediaAlbumArt(); if(art != null) {...} else {...}`

Answer (score 0):

You haven't initialized `ivListAlbumArt` anywhere, that's why you are getting *Null Pointer Exception*

Initialize `ivListAlbumArt` in `setOnItemClickListener` :

```
 lvLibList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                int position, long id) {
             ivListAlbumArt =  (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.ivListAlbumArt);
        }
 });
```

Comment: i've initialized it before `final ImageView ivListAlbumArt = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.ivListAlbumArt);`

Comment: `byte[] art = musicSrv.getMediaAlbumArt();
            if(art != null)
            {...}
            else
            {...}`

Comment: Maybe i have to add code updating ImageView in Adapter? How can i do it?

Comment: Then what is the problem now ??

Comment: So, look!
`BookFragment.mAlbumArt.setImageBitmap(bitmap); ` is working and i gets updated ImageView in another Fragment.
`ivListAlbumArt.setImageBitmap(bitmap); ` doesn't work and i get errors with same code

Comment: Even if you wrote the line `ivListAlbumArt =  (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.ivListAlbumArt);` ?? then please debug and tell us what is NULL, because NPE can be resolved by *debugging* only

Comment: Yes. _ then please debug and tell us what is NULL, because NPE can be resolved by debugging only_ What must I do?

Comment: You need to [debug the code](https://www.google.co.in/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&rlz=1C1PRFC_enIN613IN613&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=debug+android+code&spell=1) and check which variable is NULL